# HandshakeException: Connection terminated during handshake

Tags: flutter, http

Obtengo la siguiente excepción cuando hago peticiones http, **¿Qué podría estar sucediendo?** En sí la excepción se produce al realizar peticiones get.

Uso los paquetes:

```
http: ^0.12.0+2
http_interceptor: ^0.2.0
```

Nota: esto no ocurre todo el tiempo, es rara vez que se presenta

HandshakeException io_client.dart in IOClient.send

HandshakeException: Connection terminated during handshake

El interceptior corresponde a este código:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:http_interceptor/http_interceptor.dart';

class Interceptor implements InterceptorContract {

  @override
  Future<RequestData> interceptRequest({RequestData data}) async {
    if (_session != null) {
      data.headers['authorization'] = 'TOKEN';
      data.headers['content-type'] = 'application/json';
    }
    return data;
  }

  @override
  Future<ResponseData> interceptResponse({ResponseData data}) async {
    return data;
  }
}
```

Y en sí la petición http corresponde a este código

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:http_interceptor/http_client_with_interceptor.dart';
import 'package:larvia/src/interceptor/interceptor.dart';

class ApiHelper {
  HttpClientWithInterceptor client = HttpClientWithInterceptor.build(interceptors: [
    Interceptor(),
  ]);

  Future<http.Response> get(String url, {Map<String, dynamic> params}) async {
    final Uri uri = Uri(scheme: 'https', host: 'domain', path: url, queryParameters: params);
    http.Response response = await client.get(uri);
    return response;
  }
}
```

Comment: hmm en donde estás probando? debug/release? android/ios?  que packagse usas para http?

Comment: Cuáles peticiones http? Cuéntanos mostrándonos el código correspondiente (ojalá como texto)